# Access to a common method without casting objects

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a type of class which is the GeneralProduct and it looks as follows:

```
public class GeneralProduct()
{
  String label;
  Object obj;
  public GeneralProduct(String label, Object obj)
  {
     this.label = label;
     this.obj = obj;
  }
}
```

Then I have two different classes, `ProductA` and `ProductB`. These both classes have a common method called `getPrice()`. On the other hand, I have an array called `auxList`:

```
ArrayList<GeneralProduct> auxList = new ArrayList<GeneralProduct>();
auxList.add(new GeneralProduct(new ProductA(), "ProductA"));
auxList.add(new GeneralProduct(new ProductB(), "ProductB"));
```

The problem now is that I can't access `getPrice()` in classes `ProductA` and `ProductB` from the `auxList`. How could I manage this? Should I use something like this? And if so, how can I inherit the method getPrice() from the children?

```
public class ProductA extends GeneralProduct
```

Comment: getPrice() should be declared, as an abstract method, in the base GeneralProduct class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html

Comment: I may have misread the question. Why do you have `GeneralProduct` taking `ProductA`/`ProductB` as an `obj` parameter?

Comment: That class declaration does not look syntactically valid

Comment: already solved guys! thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your question, it seems like `ProductA` and `ProductB` are meant to be subclasses of `GeneralProduct`; that is, that `ProductA` "is a" `GeneralProduct`, just more specialized.

If so: Define `GeneralProduct` with an abstract `getPrice` method (but keep reading¹), which the subclasses implement. You'd probably also do away with `obj`, you don't need it:

```
public abstract class GeneralProduct {
    String label;
    public GeneralProduct(String label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public abstract double getPrice();
}

class ProductA extends GeneralProduct {
    @Override
    public double getPrice() {
        // implementation
    }
}

// and the same for ProductB
```

Then:

```
auxList.add(new ProcuctA("ProductA"));
auxList.add(new ProcuctB("ProductB"));
```

(But you can put `obj` back if you need it for something.)

Note that `getPrice` doesn't *have* to be abstract, if there's a reasonable implementation that `GeneralProduct` could provide, making overriding it in a subclass optional.

You can even take it further and separate out the interface of products from the implementation:

```
public interface Product {
    double getPrice();
}
```

Then the list would be

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
```

If you still need `GeneralProduct` (if there's a need for a base class), it can implement that interface.

```
public abstract class GeneralProduct implements Product {
    // ...
}
```

But if you don't need a base class at all, `ProductA` and `ProductB` can just implement the interface themselves.

---

**However**, inheritance is only one way to provide functionality, and sometimes it's the right way, and other times another approach is useful: Composition. In this case, `GeneralProduct` would "have a" `ProductA` or `ProductB`, but `ProductA` (and `ProductB`) wouldn't have an "is a" relationship with `GeneralProduct`.

That still probably involves an interface and/or an abstract class, just in a different place:

```
public interface Product {
    double getPrice();
}

class ProductA implements Product {
    public double getPrice() {
        // implementation
    }
}

// ...same for ProductB

public class GeneralProduct {
    String label;
    Product product;
    public GeneralProduct(String label, Product product)
    {
        this.label = label;
        this.product = product;
    }

    // You might have something like this, or not
    public double getProductPrice() {
        return this.product.getPrice();
    }
}

// Then using it:
auxList.add("ProductA", new ProcuctA("ProductA"));
auxList.add("ProductB", new ProcuctB("ProductB"));
```

Both inheritance and composition are powerful tools.

Comment: the `Object` field is unnecessary if we have chosen inheritance instead of composition

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: Indeed, I'm not entirely sure what the goal of `obj` was. This seems like an inheritance situation, but maybe I should flag up composition as an option.

Comment: exactly, if we choose inheritance i guess Object can be deleted. Thank you very much!